# Updating a custom UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm creating a custom progress bar for my app.

I have subclassed `UIView` and all the drawing is dealt with in `drawRect`.

Now, the custom progress bar has 6 properties that all change the way it gets displayed.

```
minProgress
maxProgress
progress
onColor
offColor
numberOfSections
```

These are all set to default values by the subclass but there are several places where all these values are changed in the viewWillAppear method of the controller.

At the moment I have written setter functions for all the properties that look like this...

```
- (void)setProgress:(float)progress
{
    _progress = progress;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

But does this mean that the drawRect method will be called 6 times before actually being shown on the screen? It seems like a bad way of doing it.

Am I correct about this? Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: There's no need to call `[self setNeedsDisplay];`. I have a view that manages a progress bar and I don't call this method and the progress bar change it's value when I request

Comment: There is because changing the property itself won't redraw the view. Only calling setNeedsDisplay will trigger the view to update.

Comment: I have a view that manages a progress bar and I don't call this method and the progress bar change it's value when I request

Comment: The UIProgressView already redraw itself when you set new values to the property `progress`

Comment: I'm neither subclassing UIProgressView nor am I using UIProgressView. All of this is in a UIView subclass.

Comment: Ohh yeah. That's true. You're using a custom progress bar. Sorry for my lack of attention! Anyway, the guy has already answered your doubt!

Comment: No worries :D Yep, got my answer now, thanks.

Comment: I agree with Caina. You don't need to call [self setNeedsDisplay] in ViewWillAppear. Since nothing has been drawn yet, nothing needs to be updated. You can streamline your code by creating an init method for your progressbar class and setting the values directly, rather than using the setters. Still, using setters is preferred in an init method, so it's the way I would do it. Keep it as is.

Comment: Thanks. Would do it in an init method but it gets created by the nib so I can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setNeedsDisplay` merely marks your view as needing redrawn during the next draw phase. If you call it a number of times before the next draw, it will still only get drawn the once.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So I call it 6 times in viewWillAppear but drawRect only runs once when the view actually appears. Thanks :-D